# Assign Word Table Cell values to variable in Word Document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to create 2 variable from a string in the cell. cell string is "Mr Jonhattan Smith Sun". Value1 I want as "Jonhattan" and value2 as "Smith Sun". I have the following codes but doesn't seem to work properly. any Help Please

```
value1 = Left(ThirdTable.Rows(10).Cells(2).Range.text, Len(ThirdTable.Rows(10).Cells(2).Range.text) - InStrRev(ThirdTable.Rows(10).Cells(2).Range.text, " "))

value2 = Right(ThirdTable.Rows(10).Cells(2).Range.text, Len(ThirdTable.Rows(10).Cells(2).Range.text) - InStrRev(ThirdTable.Rows(10).Cells(2).Range.text, " ") + 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try:**

```
ss = Split(ThirdTable.Rows(10).Cells(2).Range.Text, " ")

Value1 = ss(1)
Value2 = ss(2) & " " & ss(3)
```

**Given that**

`ThirdTable.Rows(10).Cells(2).Range.Text` Gives you `Mr Jonhattan Smith Sun`

**Demo:**

[image]

---

**If that Weird Letter comes up like in the Demo use:**

```
Value2 = ss(2) & " " & Left(ss(3), Len(ss(3)) - 1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Much appreciated. :)

Comment: @RALF .. Accept the Answer & Upvote if it worked for you. :)

Comment: i did. Thanks :)